# Xcode - Need constraits for Y position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Все constraints добавлены, но почему-то ругается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень темный скриншот

Comment: забыл отключить shady) Так лучше?

Comment: если на красный кружок нажать возле Missing Constraints, что там?

Comment: Добавляет к imageview width, но ошибка остается

Comment: тестовый проект можете куда-то залить?

Comment: уже исправил, просто imageview прикрепил не к tableviewcell, а верх к верху name, а низ - к phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательно куда вы цепляете верхние и нижние констрэйнты.

А вообще есть прекрасный сайт https://www.wtfautolayout.com в котором можно просто ввести лог ошибок от констрэйнтов и он выдаст рекомендации к решению.